# Provide instance instantiated in parent fragment to @Inject in children fragments in Dagger/Hilt

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am instantiating a service in a fragment that uses its `childFragmentManager` to add child fragments within it's view. I'd like for these child fragments to `@Inject` the same instance of that service that was created by the parent.

I have a parent fragment like so:

```
@AndroidEntrypoint
class ParentFragment : Hilt_ParentFragment {
  var service: SomeService = SomeService(/* ... */)

  // ...

  childFragmentManager.commit {
    add(R.id.container, ChildFragment())
  }
}
```

And I have a child fragment like so:

```
@AndroidEntrypoint
class ChildFragment : Hilt_ChildFragment {
  @Inject lateinit var service: SomeService
}
```

How can I set this up so that the `ChildFragment` injects `SomeService` from the instance instantiated by the `ParentFragment`?